# Reference Items in context

Tags: msbuild, metadata, itemgroup

I am trying to figure out a way to access the Items from the context without having to declare an ItemGroup explicitly.

Currently trying for the Copy task:

```
<Copy SourceFiles="C:\blabla\**\*.*" DestinationFiles="%(?.RecursiveDir)" />
```

What can I use in place of "?" to select the Items in context ?

The reason is that, I have an MSBuild project file being generated via XSLT and there are unknown number of folders & files (some of them follow a different structure under the destination folder - in that case I intend to use different meta data in place of RecursiveDir) in the input XML. Is it possible to achieve this without the need to declare loads of Itemgroups (or an Itemgroup with lots of Items) ?

I tried searching for this, but all I found were posts with Itemgroups declared.

Comment: You want to refer item metadata without explicitly delcaring item itself, so I have doubts you will be able to do this.
Also Copy task require that SourceFiles should be ITaskItem[] type (literaly - it require item collection).
Actually msdn description of copy task (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx) have exact example you could follow, but you should declare itemgroup with nested items clause inside.

Comment: Thanks Alexey. But explicit declaration is precisely what I was trying to avoid.Correct me if I am wrong, but my observation is that having an Item with a lot of files (a huge fileset) makes MSBuild slow down as compared to filesets with fewer number of files.

Comment: It depends =). What numbers you mean under huge fileset =). It's true that msbuild engine emit and evaluate each item group in memory, and probably huge fileset could lead to bigger memory footprint. But msbuild not adapted to work as your scripting language of choice (even powershell have issues with 250K+ files in one dir, windows itself either). If you just need perform a copy without accessing to full meta (except recursive dir)- use Exec task and invoke robocopy.exe - it works waaaay better than anything else (considering available out of the box tools).

Comment: as addition - huge number should be tested and evaluated before we declare that concrete tool isn't acceptable for that. I think as soon as msbuild could deal with big solutions - it could probably deal with pretty big filesets. It just the resource\speed question. But any tool also have it's unsurmountable limits

Comment: Robocopy MSBuild extension seems to work slightly faster. Thanks for that! But the copy with UseHardlinksIfPossible attribute worked fastest. The fileset is around 18-19 GB per build (20k files approx). I'll probably use UseHardlinksIfPossible with ItemGroup/Item. Many thanks once again. I will mark your comment about robocopy as helpful.

Comment: =) Glad to help.
Actually I meant not robocopy extension, but robocopy.exe itself (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy), you can easily call it with Exec task. 
And surely hardlinks unbeatable in terms of "copy" speed =). But keep in mind - it will work only across single disk volume (cause it's not actual copy, it just adding another file name to same set of bytes =) ). In case you need  actual copy to another drive or over the network - robocopy will shine again =).

Comment: PS: 20k files are far from my definition of huge ;) We dealt with ~280k-300k small files, summary volume around 80Gb. Powershell for plumbing and robocopy for actual bits-moving won that round.

Answer (score 0):

@Alexey Shcherbak wrote:

> You want to refer item metadata without explicitly declaring item itself, so I have doubts you will be able to do this. Also Copy task require that Source Files should be `ITaskItem[]` type (literally - it require item collection). Actually the [msdn description of copy task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx)  has an exact example you could follow, but you should declare itemgroup with nested items clause inside.
>
> You may wonder if you have an item with a lot of files, does it make MSBuild slow down. 
>   The answer is: it depends =). What numbers you mean under huge fileset =). It's true that MSBuild engine emits and evaluates each item group in memory, and probably a huge fileset could lead to a bigger memory footprint. But MSBuild is not adapted to work as your scripting language of choice (even powershell has issues with 250K+ files in one dir, windows itself also). If you just need perform a copy without accessing to full meta (except recursive dir)- use Exec task and invoke robocopy.exe - it works waaaay better than anything else (considering available out of the box tools).
>
> As an addition - huge numbers should be tested and evaluated before we declare that concrete tool isn't acceptable for that. I think as soon as MSBuild could deal with big solutions - it could probably deal with pretty big filesets. It just the resource/speed question. But any tool also have it's unsurmountable limits.
>
> Actually I meant not robocopy extension, but `robocopy.exe` itself [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy), you can easily call it with Exec task. And surely hardlinks are unbeatable in terms of "copy" speed =). But keep in mind - it will work only across single disk volume (because it's not actual copy, it just adding another file name to same set of bytes =) ). In case you need actual copy to another drive or over the network - robocopy will shine again =).
>
> PS: 20k files are far from my definition of huge ;) We dealt with ~280k-300k small files, summary volume around 80Gb. Powershell for plumbing and robocopy for actual bits-moving won that round.

Comment: ([Answered in the comments and cpnverted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments).)